# Iterating through hash

Tags: perl, hash

I'm new in here and just started to learn perl, I'm trying to access to the sub keys of the hash like this

```
my %hash = ( 'key' => {
    'subkey1' => 'value1',
    'subkey2' => 'value2',
});
```

I'm trying to do it in this way....

```
  for my $key(%hash){
      for my $sub_key(%key){
           print $hash{$key}{$sub_key}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  for my $key(keys %hash){
        for my $sub_key(keys %{$hash{$key}}){
             print $hash{$key}{$sub_key}
         }
  }
```

And you're getting an output like `value1value2...valueX`

Answer (score 0):

This can also be nicely solved using `while` and `each`:

```
while (my ($key, $hashref) = each %hash) {
    while (my ($subkey, $val) = each %$hashref) {
        print "$key -> $subkey -> $val\n";
    }
}
```